# Angle of rotation from vertical axis

Tags: android, math, pie-chart, angle, android-wheel

I am currently trying to create a meter that can be adjusted in the percentage of fill. The problem I have is I'm not good at math at all. I want to start drawing an arc in the 'north' (first image), as opposed to a normal arc having its 0 deg point in the 'east' (as shown in second image).

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

I want to be able to increase the blue area in image 1 in size (angle) by dragging/touching it along the screen. Now these are things I am able to do in some kind of fashion now. The real problem I am facing is this:

I use the following code to draw the blue area:

```
mStart = -90;
int degree = (int)((theta + Math.PI) * 180 / Math.PI);
mSweep = degree;

RectF mOvals = new RectF(c.x - outerRadius + circleThickness, c.y - outerRadius + circleThickness, c.x + outerRadius - circleThickness, c.y + outerRadius - circleThickness );

mArcSetLevel = new Path();

if(mArcSetLevel != null ) {
    canvas.drawArc(mOvals, mStart, mSweep, true, arcPaint);
}
```

Setting the start at -90 makes it start 90 deg earlier. To track the angle of the touch I use this formula, but this is where it goes wrong:

```
int py = (int)event.getY() - c.y;
int px = (int)event.getX() - c.x;

theta = (float) ((float)  Math.atan2(py, px) - (Math.PI / 2)); // - Math.PI / 2 to correct -90 start
```

When I go further than exactly 270 degrees the blue area gets reset and draws itself from north to west in a much smaller angle (because of the 'false' start of -90, shown in third image). My math skills are simply not good enough for me to be able to solve this, although I can think of why it is happening I cannot seem to find the solution.

[image: Image 3]

The (very messy) code to the entire view I made is as follows:

```
    private Canvas canvas;  

//Canvas width and height
private int h = -1;
private int w = -1;

//circle properties
private Paint paint;
private Paint arcPaint;
private Path circle;
private Point c;
private int outerRadius;
private int circleThickness = 20;

//point click in wheel
private float theta = 0;

private float mStart;
private float mSweep;
private Paint mBgPaints   = new Paint();
private Path mArcSetLevel;

int padding = 10;

OnMeterWheelChangeListener onMeterWheelChangeListener = null;

public MeterWheel(Context context){
    super(context);
    initCircleSeekBar();
}

public MeterWheel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initCircleSeekBar();
}

private void initCircleSeekBar() {

    canvas = new Canvas();
    circle = new Path();
    paint = new Paint();
    arcPaint = new Paint();
    c = new Point();

    mBgPaints.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBgPaints.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mBgPaints.setColor(0x88FF0000);
    mBgPaints.setStrokeWidth(0.5f);

    mArcSetLevel = new Path();

    this.draw(canvas);
}


@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldw, int oldh) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldw, oldh);

    w = width;
    h = height;
    Log.i("POWERWHEEL", String.valueOf(w) + "   " + String.valueOf(h));
    c.set(w/2, h/2);
    drawCircle();
}

private void drawCircle() {
    outerRadius = Math.min(h,w)/2;
    circleThickness = (int) (outerRadius*0.15);

    circle.addArc(new RectF(c.x - outerRadius + circleThickness/2, c.y - outerRadius + circleThickness/2, c.x + outerRadius - circleThickness/2, c.y + outerRadius - circleThickness/2 ), 0, 360);
    circle.moveTo(c.x, c.y);
    //paint.setShader(new SweepGradient(w/2,h/2, colourarry, null));
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(circleThickness);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    arcPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    arcPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    arcPaint.setStrokeWidth(circleThickness);
    arcPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
}


@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(circle != null){
    //draw circle
        canvas.drawPath(circle, paint);

        mStart = -90;

        int degree = (int)((theta + Math.PI) * 180 / Math.PI);
        Log.d("POWERWHEEL", "" + degree);
        mSweep = degree;

        RectF mOvals = new RectF(c.x - outerRadius + circleThickness, c.y - outerRadius + circleThickness, c.x + outerRadius - circleThickness, c.y + outerRadius - circleThickness );

        mArcSetLevel = new Path();

        if(mArcSetLevel != null ) {
            canvas.drawArc(mOvals, mStart, mSweep, true, arcPaint);
        }
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (!isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            setPressed(true);
            onStartTrackingTouch(event);
            trackTouchEvent(event);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            trackTouchEvent(event);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            trackTouchEvent(event);
            onStopTrackingTouch();
            setPressed(false);
            invalidate();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            onStopTrackingTouch();
            setPressed(false);
            invalidate();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    setMeasuredDimension(width,height);
}

private void onStartTrackingTouch(MotionEvent event) {

}

private void onStopTrackingTouch() {

}

private void trackTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int py = (int)event.getY() - c.y;
    int px = (int)event.getX() - c.x;

    theta = (float) ((float)  Math.atan2(py, px) - (Math.PI / 2));
    Log.d("POWERWHEEL", "theta: " + theta);

    this.invalidate();
}



public void setSize(int x, int y){
    h = y;
    w = x;
}

public void setCirleThickness(int t){
    circleThickness = t;
}


public void setOnMeterWheelChangeListener (OnMeterWheelChangeListener listener) {
    onMeterWheelChangeListener = listener;
}

public interface OnMeterWheelChangeListener{
    public void onStartTrackingTouch (MeterWheel colourWheel);
    public void onStopTrackingTouch (MeterWheel colourWheel);
}
```

Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calculating theta, you use atan2 which returns the angle in +/- pi. So when being in the upper left quadrant it will return a value in the range -pi/2 to -pi (asuming y is positive downwards and x is positve rightwards). You substract pi/2 directly with gives a range of -pi to -3pi/2. In onDraw you then add pi again (confusing) giving a range of 0 to -pi/2 of the sweep for this quadrant. This means it will paint the arc 0 to pi/2 (or 0 to 90 degrees) counterclockwise from your starting position at the top. You must make sure your sweep always keeps in the range 0 to pi. Nicest solution is to shift the coordinates by -pi/2, so that instead of Math.atan2(py, px), you do Math.atan2(px, -py) and then if theta is negative you add 2*pi. Something like (I don't write android)

```
theta = (float)  Math.atan2(px, -py);
if (theta < 0) theta += 2 * Math.PI;
```

and then in onDraw

```
int degree = (int)(theta * 180 / Math.PI);
Log.d("POWERWHEEL", "" + degree);
mSweep = degree;
```

If you are still experiencing problems check that mSweep is always in the range 0 to 360 degrees.

Comment: That's it! thanks a lot. Pure math like this really is my weak point, I got things all messed up. Again, thanks a million :)

Comment: @Marcel No problem, glad it worked out! Good luck with your app :)